# Node - Cannot require('./index.js') in the same folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodejs-server

I have a folder src/config in which I have multiple files a.js, b.js, c.js and index.js

When inside b.js I do

```
const data = require('./index');
```

OR

```
const data = require('./index.js');
```

I always get an empty object which is really strange

// index.js

```
module.exports = {
  a: require('./a'),
  b: require('./b'),
  c: require('./c')
}
```

And I am using this index.js and it works just fine.

So, **what I have understood from this is that requiring ./index always returns empty object**

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: So b requires index which requires b?

Comment: -> circular dependency

Answer (score 1):

Your issue comes from your approach, you require b.js in index.js where you require b again and so on.

If you require index in a other file, it shoud work as expected.

```
app.js

const data = require('src/index');
//data.b.foo = "foo"
```

```
src/index.js

module.exports = {
    a: require('./a'),
    b: require('./b'),
    c: require('./c')
  }
```

```
src/b.js

module.exports = {
    foo:"foo"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you do cause **circular dependency**.

First, node loads *index.js* then loads *a.js*,*b.js* and *c.js*.

when *b.js* is loaded, node loads *index.js*  in which is required.

node finds that *index.js* is loading.

node will return an **empty object** in *b.js* in order to prevent circular dependency.